# how to find out which website is requesting my webpage?

Tags: php

i have a webpage ... sorto like an api ... basically it prints out some data in form of json .

other website can use this data via php by simply using `file_get_contents`

or

javascript/jquery  `ajax request` (jsonp)

anyway i want to be able to black list some unwanted websites , so i have to know where this request are coming from

i've tried

```
 $url     = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
 $domain  = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

but i get

```
Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER
```

so unless i'm mistaken and this was an wierd exception , `HTTP_REFERER` doesn't work here .

so how can i get the referee in case of `file_get_contents` page request ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string.

Comment: @Marcel - actually, you're wrong. According to the [JSON reference](http://www.json.org/), "In JSON, they take on these forms:

An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma)."

Comment: Yes, the JSON string represents a specific structure, but the output itself, which the OP is sending out, is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server request it directly then you can use $_SERVER 'REMOTE_ADDR' and 'REMOTE_HOST'.

If they use javascript then you will only get the clients ip. You can use strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') to disallow jquery requests.

Comment: Don't forget `X_FORWARDED_FOR` for proxies... (and to the OP: every header can be spoofed; likewise, an IP isn't an absolute metric since there are so many proxies out there)

Comment: I wish ppl would say why they think my answer is wrong instead of simply downvoting...

Comment: I agree. Should be mandatory to leave comment on down vote (or at least list the users' names)

Answer (score 1):

Note that Ajax request are usually sent through the client's browser, while usually a server would call `file_get_contents()` or a similar tool, to fetch your page.

So in the case of a server, you can check the `REMOTE_ADDR` *HTTP header* (which contains the caller's IP) against a blacklist.

In the case of an Ajax request, probably from a user agent you can't really say from which website the originated from.

Though I am not sure, but the `HTTP_REFERER` header might contain exactly that, but again I have not checked it.

**UPDATE *(Ajax Requests)*:**
After looking up a little bit, I turn out that browsers don't send referrer data with XHR requests, so you can only blacklist the IPs of the servers you don't want to be accessed from.

Comment: At the time I wrote it I was unaware of the other answers. Also I updated my answer after doing some research, to provide additional accurate info.

Comment: thanx for the extra info about ajax part

Answer (score 0):

Isn't what you're looking for a `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`? AJAX calls probably won't have a Referer header and that's why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Referrer gets sent by a browser, probably not by file_get_contents()!

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. This will give you the raw IP address from the TCP stack.

In the case of a server-side API call, you get the server's IP (assuming the client does not use any proxies).

However if the client is an AJAX request, you'll get the IP address of the user viewing that page.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERER is not going to be reliable.  You might try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to inspect IP address of remote client.

I would however think that you would have a better time whitelisting approved clients rather then blacklisting, as an attacker could easily proxy a request to get around an IP/host-based blacklist.

There are a number of approaches for whiltelisting:

- whitelist known IP's
- HTTP Authentication
- Your own custom API keys
- Third party authentication (i.e. OAuth)

and so forth.